# Windows Shared Folders and Azure

Tags: windows, azure, smb, shared-directory

I'm transposing a legacy web application to the cloud (Windows Azure) and I am using Azure Cloud Drives to use as the storage medium for large files. I'm using worker roles to create the share (2+ instances that will compete for the mount to ensure high availability). The web roles the mount the share as a drive. That works fine.

In order to reduce my work load I need to map it as a folder inside the *siteroot* and not as a drive. How do I programmatically (batch script) map the share as a folder instead of a drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a symbolic link between the network share and your desired local path:

```
mklink /d E:\sitesroot\0\desiredDir \\rolewithshare\sharename
```